# InkToolbar UI out of sync with the target InkCanvas when updating the InkDrawingAttributes

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-universal

I'm working with the `InkCanvas` and `InkToolbar` controls and I'm having a small UI glitch whenever I update the current inking attributes for the canvas.

Let's say I have these two controls in a page:

```
<InkToolbar TargetInkCanvas="{x:Bind DrawingCanvas}"/>
<InkCanvas x:Name="DrawingCanvas"/>
```

And then in the `Loaded` event handler of the page I have something like this to set the initial inking attributes:

```
// Update the attributes
InkDrawingAttributes attributes = new InkDrawingAttributes
{
    PenTip = PenTipShape.Circle,
    Color = Colors.Red,
    // And so on...
};
DrawingCanvas.InkPresenter.UpdateDefaultDrawingAttributes(attributes);
```

The tool in use is correctly changed, so for example if I set the attributes up to use a yellow highlighter, when I start drawing I'm actually using an highlighter as expected.

**But**, the issue is that the UI of the InkToolbar control isn't updated, and it still shows the default tool as the one in use (the color in use for the highlighter isn't updated either, so if I initialize the attributes with an orange highlighter, the toolbar will still show the default yellow one).

Is this by design or is it a bug in the control? I don't see a way to explicitly set the `InkDrawingAttributes` in the toolbar, as that property is readonly (and manually setting its nested properties doesn't seem to affect the toolbar UI anyways).

**EDIT**: since the `InkToolbar` doesn't update its UI when the attributes of the target `InkCanvas` control change, I've come up with this code to *try* to solve the issue:

```
// Assume I already have the "attributes" variable with my desired settings
InkToolbarTool tool;
if (attributes.DrawAsHighlighter) tool = InkToolbarTool.Highlighter;
else tool = attributes.Kind == InkDrawingAttributesKind.Default ? InkToolbarTool.BallpointPen : InkToolbarTool.Pencil;
InkToolbarToolButton button = Toolbar.GetToolButton(tool);
Toolbar.ActiveTool = button;
```

Now, the right button gets selected correctly, but I still have no way to set a specific pen size/color. *I'll only use a color that is actually present in the original palette*, that's why I'm not worrying about what could happen if I try to set a color that's not predefined in the `InkToolbar` control.

In the end, I just want to save/restore the user ink drawing settings between different sessions, and I'd like the UI of the `InkToolbar` to follow that as well. Is there a way to do that or do I have to settle to just have the right tool button selected (with the color/size out of sync)?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: there is a problem in your edited code, `DrawingCanvas.InkPresenter.UpdateDefaultDrawingAttributes(attributes); ` should be called _after_ `Toolbar.ActiveTool = button;`, so that the drawing attribute won't get overwritten again.

Comment: @kennyzx Yeah I know that, the two code snippets in my question are not to be considered as ordered, I've added the second one after posting the initial question. I'm currently using the second snippet to at least set the right button in the `InkToolbar`, then the code in the first snippet to load the right `InkDrawingAttributes` I want to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally managed to understand how to solve this, here's the code I came up with:

```
void SetupInkToolbar(this InkToolbar toolbar, InkToolbarTool tool, Color color, double thickness)
{
    InkToolbarToolButton button = toolbar.GetToolButton(tool);
    if (button is InkToolbarPenButton typed) // Only adjust the UI if the tool is either a pen, a pencil or an highlighter
    {
        Color[] colors = typed.Palette.Select(p => (p as SolidColorBrush)?.Color ?? Colors.Black).ToArray();
        int index = colors.IndexOf(c => c.Equals(color));
        if (index >= 0) typed.SelectedBrushIndex = index; // Get the right brush index for the given color
        typed.SelectedStrokeWidth = thickness; // Adjust the brush thickness too
    }
    toolbar.ActiveTool = button;
}
```

**Note**: as also kennyzx pointed out, this code should be called before the `UpdateDefaultDrawingAttributes` method of the target `InkPresenter` object.

**Edit**: I realized that `IndexOf` method was a small extension method I wrote and not a method in the standard library, here's the code just in case:

```
///<summary>Finds the index of the first item matching an expression in an enumerable</summary>
///<param name="items">The enumerable to search</param>
///<param name="predicate">The expression to test the items against</param>
///<returns>The index of the first matching item, or -1 if no items match</returns>
public static int IndexOf<T>([NotNull] this IEnumerable<T> items, [NotNull] Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    int index = 0;
    foreach (T item in items)
    {
        if (predicate(item)) return index;
        index++;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When setting the `TargetInkCanvas` property, it is a "one-way binding", the settings of the toolbar are propagated to the associated InkCanvas, but if you set the InkDrawingAttributes of the InkCanvas in *code behind*, they are not reflected in the toolbar.

This is by design. You can set an `InkDrawingAttributes` in code behind with a color which isn't available in the palette, what do you expect the toolbar updated to reflect your choice? If you want to sync them, you need to write code to update the toolbar, like, setting the `ActiveTool` property. I don't know if it is possible to reflect the current `InkDrawingAttributes` in the toolbar, though.

Comment: I've edited my question and I've added a code snippet to select the right tool button, as suggested, but it still doesn't solve the issue as so far I haven't found a way to restore the previous pen size/color as well. Thanks!

Comment: Since I don't find any API related to updating the color/pensize in the flyout of the default buttons, so your requirement could be quite hard if not impossible to achieve. I do find something on "customized inktoolbar" but looks quite complicated. It is safe to say the toolbar is not designed to sync with inkcanvas in the first place.

Comment: Just figured out how to do it, see my answer below. And thank you for your help and your suggestions! :)